# List items position absolute in single line

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to create menu with absolute position CSS rule for each list item. `display: inline-block` for parent doesn't work. Here's an example of markup.

```css
.menu-items{
}
.main-menu{
  position: relative;
  list-style:none;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: absolute;
  float:left;
}
.main-menu li a{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
.main-menu li a:hover{
  font-size: 21px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="menu-items">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Floating and absolute positioning do not mix, as they are distinctively different layout modes. Floating takes into account the space occupied by surrounding elements, but absolute positioning takes the elements out of the document flow. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for reply, I was trying to create simple menu when on hovering ul items increase their size without moving neighbor object positions, was thinking about position absolute, but it was hard to manage items in single horizontal line. I have found solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform:scal(x);` , it won't disturb the layout.

```css
.menu-items {} .main-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu li {
  display: inline-block;/*modified*/
  padding-left: 10px;/* moved here*/
}
.main-menu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
  display: inline-block;/*added*/
  background:white;/*added*/
  transition: 0.25s;/*added*/
}
.main-menu li a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.75);/*modified*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="menu-items">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">index</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu-items {}

.main-menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.main-menu li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

.main-menu li a:hover {
  font-size: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="menu-items">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for rapid answer, but is it possible somehow to use position:absolute; for each list items? so hover resizing would not affect neighbor items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute`, too, but on `a` elements:

```css
.menu-items{
}
.main-menu{
 
  list-style:none;
}
.main-menu li {
 position:relative;
display:inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  
}
.main-menu a {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
position:absolute;

width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
top:0;
}
.main-menu a:hover{
 font-size: 21px;
 color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="menu-items">
       <ul class="main-menu">
         <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
         <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
         <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
         <li><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode a "left: XXXpx" for each li but then you will have issues based on screen sizes. If you really want that for some reason though let me know and I will send an example of that.

Another option is to use a flex box (assuming you do not need this to work with older versions of IE) like below. The spacing between items will change, but it will be responsive to the size of the text and screen , versus just pushing everything to the right.

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
  
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

.flex-item:hover {
 font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="menu-items">
       <ul class="flex-container">
         <li class="flex-item"><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
         <li class="flex-item"><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
         <li class="flex-item"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
         <li class="flex-item"><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
         <li class="flex-item"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div> 
  </div>
```